# Blueimp File Upload Pass Variable

Tags: php, jquery, session, file-upload, blueimp

I have a product pictures folder

```
> product/['product-id']/ => Original Image Path
> product/['product-id']/thumbnail/
> product/['product-id']/small/
> product/['product-id']/medium/
> product/['product-id']/large/
```

I'm using [Blueimp File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) I have to pass variable while uploading i need productID for paths. If i use $_SESSION['productid'] everything is all right except uploading more than one product simultaneously.

I tried to use $_REQUEST['productid'] instead of $_SESSION['productid']. There is no problem during upload. But an error occured during loading uploaded images.

I need to pass variables for uploading and for loading. I'm done for uploading but i couldn't handle for loading.

Here is my fileupload/server/php/index.php file

```
   `$productid = intval($_REQUEST['productid']); //intval($_SESSION['productid']);
    $dirPath = PRODUCT_IMAGE_ABSPATH;
    $url     = STATIC_HOST.PRODUCT_IMAGE_PATH;

    $options = array (
        'productid'         => $productid, //This is custom option for productid
        'accept_file_types' => '/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',
        'max_file_size'     => 768000,
        'max_width'         => 1920,
        'max_height'        => 1920,
        'min_width'         => 600,
        'min_height'        => 600,
        'upload_dir'        => $dirPath.$productid.'/',
        'upload_url'        => $url.$productid.'/',        
        'image_versions' => array(
            'thumbnail' => array(
                'upload_dir' => $dirPath.$productid.'/thumbnail/',
                'upload_url' => $url.$productid.'/thumbnail/',
                'max_width' => 80,
                'max_height' => 80
            ),

            'small' => array(
                'upload_dir' => $dirPath.$productid.'/small/',
                'upload_url' => $url.$productid.'/small/',
                'max_width' => 160,
                'max_height' => 160
            ),

            'medium' => array(
                'upload_dir' => $dirPath.$productid.'/medium/',
                'upload_url' => $url.$productid.'/medium/',
                'max_width' => 300,
                'max_height' => 300
            ),

            'large' => array(
                'upload_dir' => $dirPath.$productid.'/large/',
                'upload_url' => $url.$productid.'/large/',
                'max_width' => 600,
                'max_height' => 600
            )
        )
    );

   $upload_handler = new UploadCustom($options);`
```

And here is my fileupload/index.php file

```
    <?php   

    include_once '../../autoload.php';
    //session_start();

    ob_start();

    $U = new User();
    $C = new Cart();
    $productObj  = new Product();
    $categoryObj = new Category();

     if($U->userRole('employee')){

if (isset($_GET['pid'])){

    $type = 'uploadFile';
    $site_title = _('Upload');

 $productid = intval($_GET['pid']); //$_SESSION['productid'] = 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
    <head>
        <?php include(HEAD_META); ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo HOST; ?>/admin/fileupload/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
        <style type="text/css">
        #dropzone {
            background: palegreen;
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #dropzone.in {
            width: 600px;
            height: 200px;
            line-height: 200px;
            font-size: larger;
        }
        #dropzone.hover {
            background: lawngreen;
        }
        #dropzone.fade {
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php //include(BODYTAGS); ?>

<div id="container">
    <?php include(NAVBAR); ?>
    <?php include(HEADER); ?>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['choose_category_button'])){
            echo $productid."-".$_POST['category_id'];
            $categoryUpdateResult = ($categoryObj->updateCategory($_POST['category_id'], $productid)) ? "Kategori başarı ile güncellendi" : "Kategori Güncellemesi Başarısız";
        } 

        ?>
        <?php $product = $productObj->get_product($productid); ?>
        <?php $productObj->BreadCrumb(array(
            array('Ürün Listesi','admin/list.php'),
            array('Ürün: '.$product['stock_code'].' - '.$product['product'])
        )); 

        $categoryList = $categoryObj->deepestCategories();

        ?>
        <div class="container col-md-12">
            <p style="color:#333; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; padding:10px;"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo BASE_PATH.$productObj->get_permalink($productid, $product['product']); ?>"><?php echo $product['stock_code']." - ".$product['product']; ?></a></p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <form action="server/php/index.php?pid=<?php echo $productid; ?>" method="POST" role="form">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select id="categorylist" name="category_id" class="form-control">
                                <option value="0">  ---- (Sınıflandırılmamış) ----  </option>
                                <?php foreach($categoryList as $category) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>" <?php echo ($product['category_id'] == $category['id']) ? 'selected = "selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo "(ID: ".$category['id'].") ".$category['category']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="choose_category_button" name="choose_category_button" disabled = "disabled" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Kategori Seç</button>    
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script>
                $('#categorylist').change(function(){
                    $('#choose_category_button').removeAttr('disabled');
                });
            </script>        
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="vertical-space5"></div>
            <?php 
            if(isset($categoryUpdateResult)){
                echo $categoryUpdateResult;
            }
            ?>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <?php 
                    $prev = $productObj->hasProduct($productid, 'prev');
                    if ($prev === FALSE){//Önceki Ürün Yoksa...  ?>                
                        <button class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Önceki</button>
                    <?php } else { //Önceki Ürün Varsa... ?>
                        <a href="index.php?pid=<?php echo $prev['id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $prev['stock_code']." - ".$prev['product']; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Önceki</a>
                    <?php }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="../sort.php?pid=<?php echo $productid; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> Resimleri Düzenle</a>
                <?php 
                    $next = $productObj->hasProduct($productid, 'next');
                    if ($next === FALSE){//Önceki Ürün Yoksa...  ?>                
                        <button class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled">Sonraki <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
                    <?php } else { //Önceki Ürün Varsa... ?>
                        <a href="index.php?pid=<?php echo $next['id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $next['stock_code']." - ".$next['product']; ?>" class="btn btn-default">Sonraki <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></a>
                    <?php }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php if (is_null($product['category_id'])){ ?>

            <div style="min-height:300px; padding-top:80px;">
                <h4>Ürün kategorisi seçilmediği için resim yükleme işlemi yapamazsınız. Lütfen ürün için uygun bir kategori seçin.</h4>
            </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
            <form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
                <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
                <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
                <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                            <span>Resim Ekle...</span>
                            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                        </span>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                            <span>Yüklemeye Başla</span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                            <span>İptal</span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                            <span>Sil</span>
                        </button>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                        <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
                        <span class="fileupload-loading"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The global progress information -->
                    <div class="col-md-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                        <!-- The global progress bar -->
                        <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- The extended global progress information -->
                        <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
                <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
            </form>
            <div id="dropzone" class="fade well">Drop files here</div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).bind('dragover', function (e) {
    var dropZone = $('#dropzone'),
        timeout = window.dropZoneTimeout;
    if (!timeout) {
        dropZone.addClass('in');
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    var found = false,
        node = e.target;
    do {
        if (node === dropZone[0]) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    } while (node != null);
    if (found) {
        dropZone.addClass('hover');
    } else {
        dropZone.removeClass('hover');
    }
    window.dropZoneTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        window.dropZoneTimeout = null;
        dropZone.removeClass('in hover');
    }, 1000);
});
            </script>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
    <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
        <div class="slides"></div>
        <h3 class="title"></h3>
        <a class="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="next">›</a>
        <a class="close">×</a>
        <a class="play-pause"></a>
        <ol class="indicator"></ol>
    </div>
    <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
    <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-upload fade">
            <td>
                <span class="preview"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
                {% if (file.error) { %}
                    <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
                {% } %}
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</p>
                {% if (!o.files.error) { %}
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
                {% } %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if (!o.files.error && !i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Start</span>
                    </button>
                {% } %}
                {% if (!i) { %}
                    <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% } %}
    </script>
    <!-- The template to display files available for download -->
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade">
            <td>
                <span class="preview">
                    {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                    {% } %}
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name">
                    {% if (file.url) { %}
                        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                    {% } else { %}
                        <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                    {% } %}
                </p>
                {% if (file.error) { %}
                    <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
                {% } %}
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                    <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
                {% } else { %}
                    <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% } %}
    </script>
    <!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
    <script src="js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
    <!-- http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js -->
    <!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
    <script src="js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.min.js -->
    <!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
    <script src="js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
    <!-- http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js -->
    <!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
    <script src="js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js -->
    <!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
    <script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- The main application script -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE 8 and IE 9 -->
    <!--[if (gte IE 8)&(lt IE 10)]>
    <script src="js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({ autoUpload: true, dropZone: $('#dropzone'), formData: {
            productid: '<?php echo $productid; ?>'
        }});
    </script>
        </div>
            <?php include(FOOTER); ?>
</div>
</body> 
</html>

    <?php } ?>
<?php } else {
    $U->redirectLogin();
} ?>

<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```